# E-Ink External Manipulation

Tags: voltage, e-ink

Can I 'write' on an existing E-Ink screen using an external electric field? I tried simply applying 12 V DC with two probes to a shard of a broken kindle display, which did not influence its shade in any way. Could moar power help?

About this E-Paper technology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_Ink

On a semi-related note: How do E-Ink pigment particles retain their electrostatic charge?

Comment: A "shard"? You mean a piece of a broken display?

Comment: perhaps the display is shielded to prevent the sort of thing that you are trying to do

Comment: @Finbarr @ jsotola Yes, it is a piece that I broke off of an old display. I don't see how it could prevent what I am trying to do; it doesn't have a faraday cage around it, as far as I know.

Comment: Well, that's probably your answer right there. These displays aren't designed to be broken into pieces and still work.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I got you setup. You have a broken E-Ink display, and you try to manipulate the display with an external field without electric contact to the display?

Comment: @Finbarr I think that most of the capsules should still be intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not contacting the original electrodes, you are probably facing the problem, that the upper invisible electrode an the bottom electrode form a sort of [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). It could also be that there is another layer especially for shielding integrated.

This will negate the electric field you are applying from the outside to be effective over the bubbles. Without an electric field the charged particles won't move.

Or it is just that your field is not strong enough. The driving voltage for E-Ink displays is +/- 15 V (for fast reaction). That is applied pretty much directly over the bubble, so the field strength is rather high. You might want to increase the voltage and the exposure time. E-Ink displays can be driven with lower voltages (+/- 5 V) but then it takes significantly longer to move the particles.

Comment: Thank you! Of course I will need way more voltage over a higher distance! I will also try other displays to see if I can avoid the electrodes acting as a faraday cage.

Comment: Did this work? I have a screen that is broken that I want to reset to plain white.

Comment: @TauCraft that question-comment should probably be tagged at you as I have no idea if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can access an individual pixel, you can't change its state.
E-Ink displays consist of capsules which maintain orientation and do not use an electrostatic charge to maintain state.

Comment: The pigments are statically charged and are flipped using an electric field. Why can't I apply this from the outside?